# How can I check if a ideal has a direct sum decomposition? [GAP]

Tags: gap-system

I need a function to check if a left ideal of a Group Algebra has a direct sum decomposition or not. So, I need a functon that return *true* if the left ideal has a direct sum decomposition or *false* if the left ideal doesn't have a direct sum decomposition (so the left ideal is irreducible). Just a function that verify if a left ideal is irreducible can help too.

Is there a function to do this?

Comment: This is more mathematical than programming question - I suggest to migrate it to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gap where we have 600+ questions on GAP, and where it will hopefully receive more attention. Also, how do you construct this ideal in GAP? That may be crucial for the answer, so please add some code to demonstrate where you are at the moment with your calculation.

Comment: A more detailed version of this is now at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4071949/how-can-i-check-if-an-ideal-has-a-direct-sum-decomposition-gap